# How to execute SQL truncate table in pysark

Tags: pyspark

Am trying to truncate an Oracle table using pyspark using the below code

```
truncatesql = """ truncate table mytable  """

mape=spark.read \
      .format("jdbc") \
      .option("url", DB_URL) \
      .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
      .option("dbtable", truncatesql) \
      .load()
```

but it keeps throwing  `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` how can I truncate a table using direct SQL query ?

Comment: How about replacing `dbtable` with `query`: `.option("query", truncatesql)`

Comment: return `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Answer (score 0):

Try by **`wrapping`** your query with an **`alias`**.

**`Example:`**

```
truncatesql = """(truncate table mytable)e"""
mape=spark.read \
      .format("jdbc") \
      .option("url", DB_URL) \
      .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
      .option("dbtable", truncatesql) \
      .load()
```